# Writer must be open before it can be written to

Tags: spring-batch, partitioning

I am using Spring batch for batch processing.

Input and Output files are simple flat files. Input file contains 15000 lines of records.

I am using FlatFileItemWriter with step scope. I was trying to use partitioning to scale the spring batch application ( we are trying to process more than 100 million records)

There are two things..

1. When i use simple multi-threading without partitioning, the output file is written without any problem
2. When i use local partitioning, half of the file content is written after that i am getting "Write must be open before it can be written to".

Please help me on this?

--
Shankar.

Comment: I can't check now but I remember FlatFileItemWriter is not thread safe. Maybe a different file per thread can be a solution. After you can merge all files in a next step

Comment: Luca is correct about the `FlatFileItemWriter` not being thread safe.  Can you provide your configuration so we can better help?

Comment: Thanks guys for your help... actually i missed the step scope in the bean configuration, that was the reason it was keep throwing the error. Once i put the Scope as Step it was working..